# If each $f_n$ is radial Schwartz, and $\|f_n\|_{L^{\infty}} \geq 1,$ can we choose $\{x_n\}$ bounded with $|f_n(x_n)|\geq 1$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, supremum-and-infimum, schwartz-space

Let $f_n:\mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ be [Schwartz class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space) functions, with  $\|f_n\|_{L^{\infty}} \geq C$ for all $n$ for some fixed constant $C>0,$ and assume that $f_n(x)= f_n(|x|) $ for all $x$ and $n$.

> **Question**: Can we expect to choose $\{x_n\}\subset \mathbb R$ such that $|x_n|\leq M$ (some $M>0$ fixed )and $|f_n(x_n)|\geq C$ for all $n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take a bump function $\varphi$ with support in $(-1,1)$ with $\varphi(0) = C$ and $|\varphi(x)| \leq C$ for $x \neq 0$. Define $$f_n(x) = \varphi(n+x) + \varphi(n-x)$$

Comment: Thanks. What can we  say about the same question in the higher dimension?

Answer (score 2):

The argument proposed by $\color{darkgreen}{user159517}$ is called *sliding hump*, it is generally used as a counter example of uniform convergence, and since you use $||\cdot||_{L^\infty}$ here, no surprise that it works.

To vizualize it, we can take for instance : $\displaystyle{f_n(x)=e^{-(x-n)^2}+e^{-(x+n)^2}}$

or similarly $\displaystyle{g_n(x)=e^{-(|x|-n)^2}}$

[Drawing of the function $f_4$ .](http://fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MCwiZXEiOiJleHAoLSh4LTQpXjIpK2V4cCgtKHgrNCleMikiLCJjb2xvciI6IiMwMDAwMDAifSx7InR5cGUiOjEwMDAsIndpbmRvdyI6WyItOCIsIjgiLCItMC41IiwiMS41Il0sImdyaWQiOlsiMSIsIjAuNSJdfV0-)

It is the same in $\mathbb R^d$, just replace $|x|$ by $r=\sqrt{\sum\limits_d x_i^2}\quad$ you said yourself it was a radial function.

I searched for a decent 3D-plotter online, found some but wasn't satisfied with the result of the drawing so I figured out that putting a picture of a dog bowl was faster while being almost as accurate.

$\displaystyle{g_n(x,y)=e^{-(r-n)^2}}$

[image]

Comment: Thanks: What can we say if we raised the same question in $\mathbb R^d$?